# Split a (slow) mysql query in chunks of many primary_key ranges (id 1-100, id 101-200, ...)

Tags: python, mysql, session-cookies, fetch-api

Using mariadb version 10.5.15, Flask 2.1.2, Flask-Session 0.2.0 and python 3.9

My problem is a very slow query of my database table. Especially when the result of the query contains many rows, it takes too long.

Now I have the idea to split every query up in many queries, by just including an extra "WHERE" part like this:

- Query 1: Select ... FROM ... WHERE ... AND **primary_key > 0** AND primary_key **<= 100** ...
- Query 2: Select ... FROM ... WHERE ... AND **primary_key** **> 100** AND primary_key **<= 200** ...
- Query 3: Select ... FROM ... WHERE ... AND **primary_key** **> 200** AND primary_key **<= 300** ...
- ...

My question is if there is a better way or if this attempt brings other problems (or not)

The result of the query will afterwards be an answer to a POST request. And because I'm using sessions, I would continuously push results of each chunked query in a session variable "search_query: list".

While this search_query gets filled I check if there are enough results (or if the query is done the query is done) I sent a first chunk as response.

My guess:

1. I have to run the db query in a separate process (an extra thread with python)
2. I need a stream connection with whoever made the request
3. I won't have problems with accessing the same variable (with two processes), because only one process writes to it and I never remove elements from the variable

This is the query:

```
WITH pf 
AS (
SELECT short_description, long_description, count, unit, cost_characteristic, size, family_id, is_parent  
FROM positions 
INNER JOIN project_crafts 
USING (project_craft_id) 
INNER JOIN projects 
USING (project_id) 
WHERE ---dynamic WHERE conditions---
) 
SELECT positions.short_description, positions.long_description, positions.count, positions.unit, positions.cost_characteristic, project_crafts.size, positions.family_id, positions.is_parent  
FROM positions 
INNER JOIN pf 
ON positions.family_id=pf.family_id 
AND COALESCE(positions.is_parent, -1) <> COALESCE(pf.is_parent, -1) 
INNER JOIN project_crafts 
USING (project_craft_id) 
UNION SELECT short_description, long_description, count, unit, cost_characteristic, size, family_id, is_parent  
FROM pf
```

The query is slow, when
---dynamic WHERE conditions---
is empty. Then the query returns every single row and the JOINs get expensive (I think).

Comment: It's usually a better strategy to just optimize the query. Doing N separate queries against chunks of the table might take as long as (or longer than) the single original query. You could try to parallelize it, but each parallel thread would need its own MySQL session -- don't try to use the same MySQL session on multiple concurrent threads.

Comment: Please post as TEXT A) the entire query and B) EXPLAIN SELECT ........  so we have some idea the real complexity of a production problem.  With the information shared so far we have no idea how many tables are even involved.  And yes, if it is reasonable to continue to try to assist, we will likely ask for each TABLE touched, A) SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name; B) SHOW INDEX FROM tbl_name; and C) SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE 'tbl_name'; for table summary info.  Then someone will be able to help you avoid the nightmare you are planning.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see the rest of the query...  What columns are you fetching; are there more things in the WHERE?

```
SELECT CEILING(pk/100) * 100 AS 'through',
       COUNT(*)  AS 'how many', 
       SUM(foo)
    FROM ...
    WHERE ...
    GROUP BY CEILING(pk/100)
    ORDER BY CEILING(pk/100)
```

Comment: I added the sql statement in my question. Your example would not make a query faster, right? But it would group every 100 rows nicely?

Comment: @Timo - Somewhat faster because of the overhead of each statement.  All rows are read in either case, so the execution is "similar".  (I changed from `FLOOR` to `CEILING` to align better with your query.)